# Error while loading shared libraries: internal error

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compilation, dynamic-linking, opencv

I cross-compiled OpenCV for arm following [this guide](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/crosscompilation/arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html), and built this [sample program](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html#linux-gcc-usage).

When I first ran it like this:

```
./DisplayImage image.png
```

I got:

> ./DisplayImage: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libopencv_highgui.so.3.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So I figured it needs the library `libopencv_highgui.so.3.1`. So I added all these libs to `/lib`:

```
(1) libopencv_highgui.so
(2) libopencv_highgui.so.3.1
(3) libopencv_highgui.so.3.1.0
```

symlinks: (1) -> (2) -> (3)

But now I'm getting:

> ./DisplayImage: error while loading shared libraries:
>   lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.1: internal error

I ran `file` on both the library and the executable to check their info, and this is the output:

```
.../opencv/platforms/linux/my_build/lib$ file libopencv_highgui.so.3.1.0
libopencv_highgui.so.3.1.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=1107ba22b36437bedb37dbfe0250626c14759be9, not stripped

.../opencv_sample$ file DisplayImage
DisplayImage: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=aef57fe79d0928ca3afdff8d1b65268e1ad72e77, not stripped
```

**edit:**
Running `readelf -d DisplayImage | grep NEEDED` produces:

```
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libopencv_highgui.so.3.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libopencv_core.so.3.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [ld-linux-armhf.so.3]
```

I found all of them on my target except `ld-linux-armhf.so.3`.

What could be causing this "internal error" problem?

Comment: Are you on Android? Or some other platform? Also be aware of CMake. It may be a cross-platform makefile generator, but it does a rather poor job at times. We tried to supply one [in our project](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt), but we had to yank it from the distribution because it had [so many problems](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=label%3Acmake).

Comment: I'm on arm linux (Yokto). Yeah you might be right... I am using cmake. I just gave it up and switched to Ubuntu. There I can just `sudo apt-get install` it and go.

Answer (score 2):

when a binary is compiled it can use shared libraries, these libaries are references with a version number so that you attain a library verion that is supported.

sometimes you can get away with sym linking a newer libary to an older name, the binary will attempt to use this one.

however this does not mean the binary will support that version. Some functions may have changed, some functions removed or added, so on.

Therefore i'd suggest re-compiling the binary against a newer libary version, an incompatibilities will be flagged at compile time.

you can see library dependencies using ldd.

Example;

```
$ ldd /bin/ls
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc65ff3000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f9033f91000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9033bf1000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f9033979000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9033771000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000558f25845000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9033551000)
```

Edit: ps... you can't just copy across libs as they have their own dependencies. your cross-compile machine will need similar lib versions to compile against.

Comment: I meant that I crossed compiled the libs on my host machine (Ubuntu) and then copied them to my target (arm)

Comment: don't copy libs across, compile static or cross compile for the destination host's libs.

Comment: Again, I cross compiled for the destination... Then copied them there. I don't understand what's the problem...

Comment: Why upvote this answer? It's wrong and not eligible to take the bounty.

Comment: 1. what is output of ldd DisplayImage, 2. you can't copy "libopencv_highgui.so.3.1.0" from the build machine (it has it's own dependencies there). 3. you can't sybolic link libopencv_highgui.so.4 to libopencv_highgui.so.3.1.0 on dest machine, it's a different version. 4. compile static on src machine to use libopencv_highgui.a. 5. compile to use libopencv_highgui.so.4 or whatever the version is on dest machine.

Comment: 1. `ldd` on host produces `not a dynamic executable` because it's not built for the host. So I ran `readelf` (see post). 2. Of course I can - this is cross-compilation. 3. Who said I'm doing that? 4. Wrong. Companies ship you shared libraries too - how they do that? Just like me 5. Man, cross compilation...